# matching any x out of n criteria in the where statememt

Tags: mysql

I was just wondering, is there some efficient way or standardised methodology to apply in a mySql query to get partial match of the criteria?

For instance, assume we have a table like
`id, column1, column2, column3, column4, column5`

and we have a query like
`SELECT * from my_table where column1 = 5, column2 = 10, column3 > 20, column4 = 30, column5 = 'interesting'`

so, is there some nice way to say, return all rows where 3 out of the 5 criteria match. We don't care which ones, just as long as at least 3 out of 5 are satisfied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * from my_table 
WHERE 
(column1 = 5) + 
(column2 = 10) + 
(column3 > 20) + 
(column4 = 30) + 
(column5 = 'interesting') 
>= 3
```

Each comparision equals either true or false (1 or 0).